# «Соседство – приятное и не очень». Верны ли знаки препинания?

Tags: пунктуация

«Соседство – приятное и не очень» или без ничего «Соседство приятное и не очень». Это заголовок к статье про то, какие растения можно садить рядом на огородах.

Answer (score 2):

Если это **общий заголовок статьи**, то лучше использовать уже предложенный вариант: Соседство на грядке – приятное и не очень.

Если это **подзаголовок темы** (а теперь поговорим о соседстве растений), то такой вариант подойдет: Соседство – приятное и не очень.

Лучше использовать **тире,** тогда это будет обособленное определение. **Двоеточие** больше подходит для других случаев.

**О двоеточии в заголовках**

Вопрос № 287450
Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно оформить в плане пунктуации заголовки...

Ответ справочной службы русского языка

Д. Э. Розенталь рекомендовал ставить **двоеточие в газетных заголовках,** распадающихся на две части с четким интонационным делением, отличающиеся смысловой насыщенностью, предельной краткостью, нередко и эмоциональной выразительностью. Первая часть называет **общую проблему**, место действия, лицо, а вторая – содержит **конкретизацию** названного в первой части:

Экономическая реформа: опыт, проблемы, трудности;

Разоружение: концепция, проблемы, механизм;

Россия — Западная Европа: выгоды и перспективы сотрудничества;

Звёздный рейс: работа на отлично!

Answer (score 0):

Тире не требуется, но поставить можно. Более уместным оно будет, если чуть изменить фразу. Например, так: *Соседство на грядке – приятное и не очень*. Здесь можно и двоеточие.

Answer (score 0):

Постановка знака препинания полностью зависит от смысла. Приведу соответствующие примеры:

1. **Соседство (есть какое? То есть употребление составного именного сказуемого) приятное (первое однородное сказуемое) и не очень (второе однородное сказуемое, причём неполное)** Вполне возможный случай, однако в нашем случае не имеет логического смысла, т.к. один предмет не может иметь сразу два **постоянных состояния**, противоречащих друг другу и не имеющих хоть каких-то поясняющих слов. Другое дело — употребление иного глагола связки, способного разъяснить смысл сказанного. Данный вариант нам не подходит.

//*ошибочная часть*
2. Совсем другой случай, где это сочетание выступает в роли обособленного определения, относящегося к нарицательному имени и стоящего после него. Здесь возможно несколько вариантов обособления, зависящих от смысловой нагрузки. Можно поставить запятые, являющиеся нормативными в таких случаях, а можно — тире, подчёркивающее важность последующих определений. Оба варианта уместны, но лучше придерживаться второго, как я считаю.
//*конец ошибочной части*

Спасибо Niemand за идею. **В данном случае тире и запятая могли бы быть уместными только в том случае, когда у нас были бы различные признаки.**

**начало правки #2**

Специально поясню данный фрагмент. Приведу всё тот же пример:

"Соседство, хорошее или не очень"

Здесь сочетания "хорошее" и "не очень" "выступают" в роли обособленных определений. Хорошо, допустим, что это так. Тогда можно охарактеризовать данное слово с помощью этих определений: хорошее и нехорошее(чтобы было понятнее) соседство. Однако получаем некоторый каламбур, связанный с тем, что соседство не может быть определено положительным и таким же, но уже отрицательным признаком. Тогда можно сказать, что здесь делается некоторый выбор разновидностей данного понятия (причём очень сильно сбивает то, что слово "соседство" не имеет формы множественного числа, которое мы привыкли видеть при выборе), один из которых подразумевает "хорошее" соседство, а другой — "плохое" соседство. Таким образом, данные прилагательные **не являются** однородными по отношению к **одному** предмету, а характеризуют целую группу. Отсюда следует, что и обособленным такое определение быть не может, поэтому появляется двоеточие, разделяющее обобщающее и обобщаемые слова.

**конец правки #2**

Однако одно из определений является отрицанием первого, что не является характеристикой одного и того же предмета. Поэтому наиболее оптимальным вариантом является двоеточие, где "соседство" — определяемое (главное) слово, а "хорошее" и "не очень" — однородные члены, выполняющие роль дополнений и выраженные субстантивированными прилагательными(то есть отчасти получаем неполноту)

Ответ: ставим двоеточие.

Comment: то есть с тире?

Comment: Как Вам угодно. Оба варианта второго пункта уместны. Но я бы выбрал тире.

Comment: Хотя знаете что... Нет, тире и запятая здесь не подходят. Сейчас отредактирую ответ.

Comment: *>> В данном случае тире и запятая могли бы быть уместными только в том случае, когда у нас были бы различные признаки* Ну вот откуда вы это берете?!

Comment: Логический анализ. Сейчас отредактирую ответ, а то в комментариях писать неудобно.

Comment: Столько слов - и все впустую. Даже прочитать не смог.